# Dropdown problems

Tags: html, css

I'm having a really tricky time trying to pull this off.
I have created an e-commerce website.

Here is the link to what I am doing: https://jsfiddle.net/knopy14w/3/

HTML:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/** HEADER **/


/* Heading Bar (Top) */

.top_navbar {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-align: right;
    height: 40px;
}

.top_navbar a {
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.top_navbar a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
    text-decoration: underline;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.feedback-question-css {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.feedback-question-css p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.checkboxoptions_products_choice {
    columns: 50px 2;
}

.modal-title,
.feedback-indquestion-css,
.modal-header h5 {
    color: rgb(47, 141, 255);
}

.help-us-get-better,
.customize-what-you-see-when-you-visit-us {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Nav Bar */

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fbfbfd;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(152, 152, 152);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(152, 152, 152);
}

.company_logo {
    line-height: 55px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 40px;
}

.company_card_logo {
    width: 120px;
}

.nav_options {
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    font-style: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 200px;
}

.nav_options ul {
    height: 35px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav_options li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nav_options ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

.nav_options ul li a {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
    padding: 20px 35px 20px 35px;
}

.nav_options ul li a:hover {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(142, 204, 255);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav_options ul li ul li {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(45, 100, 245);
    padding: 4px 1px 3px 1px;
}

.nav_options ul li ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px 1px 3px 1px;
}

.nav_options ul li ul li a {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    width: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

.nav_options ul li ul li a:hover {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

.nav_options ul li ul li ul li a {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: rgb(145, 144, 144);
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.nav_options ul li ul li ul li a:hover {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(52, 239, 0);
    border-bottom: none;
}

.nav_options li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav_options li a:hover,
.nav_options ul li a:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
}

.nav_options li ul {
    background: #ffffff;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.nav_options li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav_options li li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 350px;
}

.nav_options li:hover li a {
    background: none;
}

.nav_options li ul a {
    display: block;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav_options li ul a:hover,
.nav_options li ul li:hover a {
    background: white;
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_options p {
    clear: left;
}

.nav_options li ul li ul {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

.nav_options li ul li ul li {
    float: none;
}

.navbar .company_card_logo {
    align-items: baseline;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footwear_mensub_trainers {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: grey;
}

.rounded-pill {
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(207, 206, 206);
}

.rounded-pill:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(142, 204, 255);
}

#search_pill:hover,
.form-check-input:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(142, 204, 255);
}

.nav_options .mens_sub {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}


/* Second Nav Bar */

.signupforalerts_navbar {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-color: #239f93;
    height: 40px;
}

.signupforalerts_navbar a {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    padding-top: 12px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.signupforalerts_navbar a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
       <!-- Heading Bar (Top)-->
    <header>

        <div class="top_navbar">
            <!-- Top Bar (Feedback/Register/SignIn)-->
            <div>
                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#feedback" class="btn btn_feedback">Feedback</a>
                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#register" class="btn btn_register">Register</a>
                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#sign_in" class="btn btn_sign_in">Sign in</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="company_logo col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <a href="clothing.html">
                    <img class="company_card_logo " type="button" src="Images/AsNop Logo.png" alt="Company Logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /Logo -->

            <!-- Nav Menu -->
            <nav class="nav_options col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Men</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="footwear.html">FOOTWEAR</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Trainers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Boots</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Slippers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="mens-clothing.html">CLOTHING</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Tracksuits</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">See All</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="Accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Loungewear</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="# ">Women</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="footwear.html">FOOTWEAR</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Trainers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Boots</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Shoes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Slippers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="womens-clothing.html">CLOTHING</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Jackets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Tracksuits</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">See All</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="Accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Loungewear</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kids</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="footwear.html">FOOTWEAR</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Trainers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Boots</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Shoes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Slippers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="kids-clothing.html">CLOTHING</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Jackets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Tracksuits</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">See All</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="Accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Loungewear</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Accessories.html">Accessories</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">All Bags</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sports Equipment</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- /Nav Menu -->

            <div class="search_pill col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
                <!-- Search Form-->
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control rounded-pill me-2 " id="search_pill " type="search " placeholder="Search " aria-label="Search ">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle " type="submit ">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg " width="15 " height="15 " fill="currentColor "
                            class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16 ">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd "
                                d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z " />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd "
                                d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z " />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="signupforalerts_navbar">
            <div>
                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#sign_up_alert" class="btn btn_signupforalerts">SIGN UP FOR ALERTS!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

There are 2 things I am trying to achieve here:

1. When I scroll down from the Nav dropdown (say option 'Men') as the cursor goes over the child options (say 'Footwear' or 'boots') the highlight around the 'Men' dropdown heading completely disappears. I need it to keep showing the highlight on the tab as I scroll through the options in the sub menu.
2. Also: The grey underline disappears from the child-heading (for example 'Footwear') when I scroll over a child-option (for example 'Trainers' or 'Boots' etc) how do I keep the grey border-bottom to stay under the child-heading (for example 'Footwear') when I am scrolling through the specific child-options?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that your problem could be fixed easily with javascript. But i guess you want to keep this simple and use only html css.
I used the ~ selector to fix the 2 problems.
You can give a title to an element and then target it with the ~ selector.

Here's the code

HTML

```
<!-- Heading Bar (Top)-->
<header>

    <div class="top_navbar">
        <!-- Top Bar (Feedback/Register/SignIn)-->
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#feedback" class="btn btn_feedback">Feedback</a>
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#register" class="btn btn_register">Register</a>
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#sign_in" class="btn btn_sign_in">Sign in</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="company_logo col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a href="clothing.html">
                <img class="company_card_logo " type="button" src="Images/AsNop Logo.png" alt="Company Logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /Logo -->

        <!-- Nav Menu -->
        <nav class="nav_options col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
            <ul>
                <li><a title="parent" href="#">Men</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a title="child" href="footwear.html">FOOTWEAR</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Trainers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Boots</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Slippers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="child" href="mens-clothing.html">CLOTHING</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tracksuits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">See All</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="child" href="Accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Loungewear</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a title="parent" href="# ">Women</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a title="child" href="footwear.html">FOOTWEAR</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Trainers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Boots</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Shoes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Slippers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="child" href="womens-clothing.html">CLOTHING</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Jackets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Tracksuits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">See All</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="child" href="Accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Loungewear</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="women_sub">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a title="parent" href="#">Kids</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a title="child" href="footwear.html">FOOTWEAR</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Trainers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Boots</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Shoes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Slippers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="child" href="kids-clothing.html">CLOTHING</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Jackets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Tracksuits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">See All</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="child" href="Accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Loungewear</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Track Pants & Joggers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Sweatshirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="kids_sub">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a title="parent" href="Accessories.html">Accessories</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">All Bags</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sports Equipment</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /Nav Menu -->

        <div class="search_pill col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
            <!-- Search Form-->
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control rounded-pill me-2 " id="search_pill " type="search " placeholder="Search "
                    aria-label="Search ">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle " type="submit ">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg " width="15 " height="15 " fill="currentColor "
                        class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16 ">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd "
                            d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z " />
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd "
                            d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z " />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="signupforalerts_navbar">
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#sign_up_alert" class="btn btn_signupforalerts">SIGN UP
                FOR ALERTS!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/** HEADER **/

/* Heading Bar (Top) */

.top_navbar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: right;
  height: 40px;
}

.top_navbar a {
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.top_navbar a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.feedback-question-css {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.feedback-question-css p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.checkboxoptions_products_choice {
  columns: 50px 2;
}

.modal-title,
.feedback-indquestion-css,
.modal-header h5 {
  color: rgb(47, 141, 255);
}

.help-us-get-better,
.customize-what-you-see-when-you-visit-us {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Nav Bar */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fbfbfd;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(152, 152, 152);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(152, 152, 152);
}

.company_logo {
  line-height: 55px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}

.company_card_logo {
  width: 120px;
}

.nav_options {
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  font-style: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

.nav_options ul {
  height: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_options li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav_options ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_options ul li a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
  padding: 20px 35px 20px 35px;
}

.nav_options ul li a:hover {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(142, 204, 255);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav_options ul li:hover [title~="parent"] {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(142, 204, 255);
}

.nav_options ul li ul li {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(45, 100, 245);
  padding: 4px 1px 3px 1px;
}

.nav_options ul li ul li:hover {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 4px 1px 3px 1px;
}

.nav_options ul li ul li:hover [title~="child"] {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

.nav_options ul li ul li a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  width: 200px;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222); */
}

.nav_options ul li ul li a:hover {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

.nav_options ul li ul li ul li a {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: rgb(145, 144, 144);
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.nav_options ul li ul li ul li a:hover {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(52, 239, 0);
  border-bottom: none;
}

.nav_options li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_options li a:hover,
.nav_options ul li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
}

.nav_options li ul {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 700px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.nav_options li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav_options li li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 350px;
}

.nav_options li:hover li a {
  background: none;
}

.nav_options li ul a {
  display: block;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav_options li ul a:hover,
.nav_options li ul li:hover a {
  background: white;
  border: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_options p {
  clear: left;
}

.nav_options li ul li ul {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
}

.nav_options li ul li ul li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar .company_card_logo {
  align-items: baseline;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.footwear_mensub_trainers {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
}

.rounded-pill {
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(207, 206, 206);
}

.rounded-pill:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(142, 204, 255);
}

#search_pill:hover,
.form-check-input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(142, 204, 255);
}

.nav_options .mens_sub {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

/* Second Nav Bar */

.signupforalerts_navbar {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #239f93;
  height: 40px;
}

.signupforalerts_navbar a {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  padding-top: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.signupforalerts_navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Only problem is the border-bottom (underline) under the "child" (for example "Footwear", "Clothing" & "Accessories") only appears when I scroll down to a particular sub-item (e.g "Boots", "bags", "loungewear" etc). I need the border-bottom to be fixed under "Footwear", "Clothing" & "Accessories"  in the dropdown list, when I click on the dropdown item (for e.g "Men"). Thanks.

Comment: So you dont need to put the border inside the :hover.